# vs studio 2015 with XP and wix 3.10.2

Tags: visual-c++, wix, windows-xp, wix3, wix3.10

We are using visual studio 2015 with wix 3.10.2015.

when installing on a win7 32 bit we have no issues

when installing on XP we get the following error when calling the custom action in the dll.

```
Action start 16:03:50: MyCustomAction.
Action ended 16:03:51: MyCustomAction. Return value 3.
Action ended 16:03:51: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

here is the declaration from the customAction.cpp file :

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) UINT __stdcall MyCustomAction(MSIHANDLE hInstall);

extern "C" UINT __stdcall MyCustomAction(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    // commented out code 
    return WcaFinalize(er);
}
```

wix declaration:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="myCustomAction" After='AppSearch' ></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Any ideas ? clues ? directions would be extremely appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your Visual C++ project is built with "modern" toolset and you should use the "legacy" toolset version that supports Windows XP.

[Configuring C++ 11 Programs for Windows XP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139.aspx)